# The interaction between system call, virtual file system, block subsystem and block device drivers

Tags: linux, driver, device

I know how some system calls like `sys_read` and `sys_write` work with character device files. If I understand correctly, because character device drivers implement file_operations functions so `sys_read` and `sys_write` will call the read and write functions defined and implemented inside character device drivers.
However, I don't know exactly the interaction between `sys_read`, `sys_write` and regular files (which are stored in block devices) through `VFS`, Block subsystem and Block device drivers. I know that in order to read/write block devices, the drivers of the block devices have request functions which manipulate the request queues but when I read the Linux source code (`fs/read_write.c`), I cannot find any piece of code to make the request and send to any request queues.
Could you help me to clarify the interaction.
Thank you very much.